# How to render data dynamically and update the changes in real time

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Java and android studio this is my first project so any help for this would help a lot. We are trying to build an app which can display ceratin real time data in a widget, right now just for trial we are tring with random number generator, it is working fine but the issue is we have to close the app and come back again to see any changes in the widget used.I have used anychart for this purpose, following the repository : [here](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android)

Currently, we have tried to deploy the thermometer chart which can be found [here](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/anychart/sample/charts/ThermometerActivity.java).

I have tried using timer but that's of no help

`MainActivity.java` looks like this :

```
  package com.anychart.sample.charts;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.anychart.AnyChart;
import com.anychart.AnyChartView;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.SingleValueDataSet;
import com.anychart.charts.LinearGauge;
import com.anychart.enums.Anchor;
import com.anychart.enums.Orientation;
import com.anychart.enums.Position;
import com.anychart.sample.R;
import com.anychart.scales.Base;
import com.anychart.scales.Linear;

public class ThermometerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart_common);

        AnyChartView anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
        anyChartView.setProgressBar(findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));

        LinearGauge linearGauge = AnyChart.linear();

        // TODO data
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
        linearGauge.data(new SingleValueDataSet(new Integer[] { random }));

        linearGauge.tooltip()
                .useHtml(true)
                .format(
                        "function () {\n" +
                        "          return this.value + '&deg;' + 'C' +\n" +
                        "            ' (' + (this.value * 1.8 + 32).toFixed(1) +\n" +
                        "            '&deg;' + 'F' + ')'\n" +
                        "    }");

        linearGauge.label(0).useHtml(true);
        linearGauge.label(0)
                .text("C&deg;")
                .position(Position.LEFT_BOTTOM)
                .anchor(Anchor.LEFT_BOTTOM)
                .offsetY("20px")
                .offsetX("38%")
                .fontColor("black")
                .fontSize(17);

        linearGauge.label(1)
                .useHtml(true)
                .text("F&deg;")
                .position(Position.RIGHT_BOTTOM)
                .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_BOTTOM)
                .offsetY("20px")
                .offsetX("47.5%")
                .fontColor("black")
                .fontSize(17);

        Base scale = linearGauge.scale()
                .minimum(-30)
                .maximum(40);
//                .setTicks

        linearGauge.axis(0).scale(scale);
        linearGauge.axis(0)
                .offset("-1%")
                .width("0.5%");

        linearGauge.axis(0).labels()
                .format("{%Value}&deg;")
                .useHtml(true);

        linearGauge.thermometer(0)
                .name("Thermometer")
                .id(1);

        linearGauge.axis(0).minorTicks(true);
        linearGauge.axis(0).labels()
                .format(
                        "function () {\n" +
                        "    return '<span style=\"color:black;\">' + this.value + '&deg;</span>'\n" +
                        "  }")
                .useHtml(true);

        linearGauge.axis(1).minorTicks(true);
        linearGauge.axis(1).labels()
                .format(
                        "function () {\n" +
                        "    return '<span style=\"color:black;\">' + this.value + '&deg;</span>'\n" +
                        "  }")
                .useHtml(true);
        linearGauge.axis(1)
                .offset("3.5%")
                .orientation(Orientation.RIGHT);

        Linear linear = Linear.instantiate();
        linear.minimum(-20)
                .maximum(100);
//                .setTicks
        linearGauge.axis(1).scale(linear);

        anyChartView.setChart(linearGauge);
    }
}
```

I expected the thermometer to vary with every number generated but it changes the value only when I close the app and go in again

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow phoenix. I haven't written any android mobile app code in a minute but it looks like you're not getting the expected results as you whole code which sets up the `ThermometerActivity` runs in a single instance (as it should). Also, one random number is generated and `setChart()` and all the code that precedes it runs in the `onCreate()` method which executes its body only once (as its name suggests on `Activity` creation). Consider having elements such as a button to generate further random numbers and updated the activity accordingly to see any changes.

Comment: Button would help, but later I have to link this app to take up real time data, that time having button won't be useful

Comment: when that time comes, depending on how you get your data it's very likely you'll be dealing with [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you need to close your app to update your thermometer. That's because `onCreate` is called everytime the app opens.

`Timer` should work. Maybe you're using the Timer wrong. This should update your thermometer periodically.

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // you should only update UI in the main/ui thread
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // do your updating here
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 16, 16); // 60 fps
```